# Migrating queries from Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, migration

I have problems with migrating queries from Oracle to Microsoft SQL Server.

I have this Oracle query but I don't know where to start to make it work with SQL Server:

```
SELECT to_char(SYSDATE+'0','YYYY-MM-DD') as currentsys FROM DUAL
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SHOUTING DEMANDS TO DO YOUR WORK FOR YOU

Comment: You should do the formation in front end application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe either

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120) AS currentsys
```

or

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111), '/', '-') AS currentsys
```

will work.